# Does Ubuntu support My Hardware?

Tags: 12.04, games, hp-pavilion

Hello im new in this Community, i liked Ubuntu OS but i don't know if Ubuntu support My Hardware is a HP Pavilion dv4-4075la entertainment PC and this is his Hardware.

[This are the specs of my pc](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02901644&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&cc=us&destPage=siteHome&dlc=en&lc=en&product=5113863&query=pavilion%20dv4-4075la%20entertainment%20pc&tool=)

i want to play games like Team fortress 2, Sims 3 (i know i need to use virtual box or Playonlinux) my computer actually have Windows 7 Home basic and runs those games at medium high, i dont want to have lag on those games.
Another thing, i want to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my PC:D

And sorry for my bad english i'm a noob in the english.Greeting!

Comment: boot the live usb and find out =) In general I have had reasonable luck with HP products.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, and Hunter_115 - you can use a Live Disk as well, as your computer apparently has a `SuperMulti DVD Burner`.

Comment: Aye, but DVD are so expensive for testing =)

Comment: I will try the live USB to see the results. ;D and i will do it right now! windows will Hate me ;D   Greetings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell from the amount of information give, but yes, the computer should work with Ubuntu 12.04.

Installation instructions can be found [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support).

For Team Fortress 2, there is a old question here that might help:
[Is there a way to get Team Fortress 2 working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50309/is-there-a-way-to-get-team-fortress-2-working)

You can find what works on PlayOnLinux [here](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/supported_apps-1-0.html).

As bodhi.zazen says, just try the Live Disk and find out. 
 You can find out more about what it is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubiquity_%28software%29).

Comment: I will do it right now and i will post the results. Greetings! i will test the 64bit OS because i have 4GB of RAM.

Comment: @Hunter_115 - You don't have to use 64bit, you can use 32bit [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) - which works fine, and is now the default install. You can use what you like.

Comment: so i can download the 32bit version and is going to work well because they recommend 64bit for pc with 4GB of ram or more.... i will download the 32bit version and test it

Comment: Both should work well, 64bit works well on new PCs, 32bit will work on new and old. There is not too much difference, and 64bit can now run 32bit programs. There was a question on that [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose).

Comment: i will return to windows and download the 32bit version, to see you have reason no much difference. a dont have less and more im in the medium zone zone just 4GB of ram. so yes.

Comment: I'm Downloading Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 bit version ;D let's see how this will work.

Comment: success i installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS no more windows, but i dont know if this driver: ATI/AMD Proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (**experimental** beta) i should let as default thats all cheers!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Linux is not made to be a gaming platform, don't be surprised if you have lags. maybe they will work perfectly, maybe not.

I have an hp myself, very **similar** to you, more powerful 8gb ddr3. I hope Linux  works on your machine, I'll talk about what I know. On my PC:

- [I had problems with Wifi drivers.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253257/ubuntu-doesnt-reconnect-to-wifi-unless-i-reboot)
- On ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I had to set [nomodeset](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132) to make unity work. Newer versions never worked no matter what I do.
- Suspend and Log out mode did not work because of a graphic card issue,
  the screen goes black forever, I had to force shut down using the
  power button.

I had these problems, or at least one of them with every Linux distro I used: Archbang, Manjaro, Crunchbang, Linux Mint (Mate and Cinnamon), Linux Mint debian, Fuduntu, Ubuntu. I hope I didn't forget a distro :)

However, now I'm on [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) 13.10 (The latest version) and it works like a charm out of the box on my PC. Xfce is working perfectly, and for some reason I am not experiencing any errors whatsoever. Besides Xfce is lighter than unity, giving you more recourses to play. And in my personal opinion Xfce is much more beautiful that unity.

Comment: Im Testing ubuntu right now, and everything is working perfectly the wifi, bluetooth and the sound, the computer seems to be new now (actually testing Ubuntu) and i got those problems only in my other HP (that pc was using windows 8 before installing it i format that pc) now is using ubuntu and no problems. but  your problem was with the graphic card, the mine is working perfectly, but remember that windows attack when you are using another OS in the pc(if you are using two systems in one pc). and im using ubuntu because windows f*ck my other pc, trust me.

Comment: @Hunter_115 Yep, you are right. I now removed windows permanently and I'm on Xubuntu, no longer dualbooted

Comment: @Fischer - it varys with different Graphics Cards, sometimes you just have to sort out the drivers a bit, which is fairly easy. That removes 2/3 out of your list - for the wifi you can try [here](http://wireless.kernel.org/). I think I agree though, Xfce is far better than Unity - also removes some graphics related issues. Hunter_115, windows can do that yes :-), hope you enjoy Ubuntu.

Comment: @wilf Yes I know how to fix the issues, I was just telling hunter what could be expect.

Comment: @Fischer - I know, I just threw that in to see if it would be helpful.